# UglifyJsPlugin wont keep class and function names in angular build

Tags: angular, webpack, uglifyjs

In my angular.json (8) I have this:

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            }
  .....
```

this is my webpack config:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
          mangle: true,
          keep_fnames: true,

        },
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

but still when I call `constructor.name` the name is `"e"` instead of `HomeComponent`

the `constructor.name` works in dev, but when running `ng build --prod` this gets minified.

whats wrong with my `UglifyJsPlugin` ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Ben - Sorry, I did not. and thanks god I'm now using REACT.